# Python Unresolved Import Error

Tags: python

I am writing my first Python project and I cannot understand why I am getting an unresolved import error.  I have 2 classes - apiProcessor and apiDetail.  In apiProcessor I am trying to call a method from apiDetail.  The method is there but the import is failing to resolve.  Both are in the same package within the same PyDev project.

APIDETAIL

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api import declared_attr

    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://efultz:twalker1@localhost:3306/apidb", echo=False)

    Base = declarative_base(engine)
    ########################################################################
    class apiDetail(Base):
        """"""
        __tablename__ = 'api_detail'
        __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def loadSession():
        """"""
        metadata = Base.metadata
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()
        return session

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        session = loadSession()
        res = session.query(apiDetail).all()
        for entry in res:
            print ('id: ', entry.api_id, ' description: ', entry.description, ' url: ', entry.url, 'json: ', entry.json)
```

APIPROCESSOR (trying to call loadSession from APIDETAIL)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from apiDetail import apiDetail

class apiProcessor:

    def build_test_objects(self):
        session = apiDetail.loadSession()
        res = session.query(apiDetail).all()
        for entry in res:
            print ('id: ', entry.api_id, ' description: ', entry.description, ' url: ', entry.url, 'json: ', entry.json)

        return res    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = build_test_objects()
    for entry in res:
        print ('api id: ', entry.api_id, ' description: ', entry.description, ' url: ', entry.url, 'json: ', entry.json)
```

Comment: Please add a complete traceback of the error to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing Java not python ;)

Anyway, the problem is that `from apiDetail import apiDetail` imports a module `apiDetail` from `apiDetail` package. That's not what you are trying to do. Use `import apiDetail` instead ... and then access the class as `apiDetail.apiDetail` ... and then rewrite your code to python :).